# How to create a Dataset from a sequence of maps?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Why do the following fails?

```
val fd:Dataset[Map[Int, Int]] = Seq(Map(1->2, 3->4), Map(5->6), Map(8->9)).toDS()
    error: value toDS is not a member of Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]]
```

whereas this works:

```
val cd:Dataset[Array[Int]] = Seq(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(100)).toDS()
    cd: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Array[Int]] = [value: array<int>]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the SQLImplicits Map encoder was only added in Spark 2.3.0.
Upgrade to 2.3.0 and it's going to work.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L170-L172

```
// Maps
/** @since 2.3.0 */
implicit def newMapEncoder[T <: Map[_, _] : TypeTag]: Encoder[T] = ExpressionEncoder()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can upgrade to Spark 2.3 - it's probably the best idea as Traian suggested. Workarounds are possible for Spark 2.0 (tested on 2.0.2):

1) Convert `Map` to `Seq`:

```
scala> val seq2 = Seq(Map(1->2, 3->4), Map(5->6), Map(8->9)).map(_.toSeq)
seq2: Seq[Seq[(Int, Int)]] = List(ArrayBuffer((1,2), (3,4)), ArrayBuffer((5,6)), ArrayBuffer((8,9)))

scala> val ds = seq2.toDS()
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Seq[(Int, Int)]] = [value: array<struct<_1:int,_2:int>>]

scala> ds.printSchema()
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)


scala> ds.collect().foreach(println)
WrappedArray((1,2), (3,4))
WrappedArray((5,6))
WrappedArray((8,9))
```

2) Wrap into a `struct` with a case class (note that I had to use `scala.collection.Map` in case class definition for Spark 2.0 due to another bug that should have been fixed in 2.1/2.2 branches https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18717)

```
scala> case class WrapMap[K, V](m: scala.collection.Map[K, V])
defined class WrapMap

scala> val seq3 = Seq(Map(1->2, 3->4), Map(5->6), Map(8->9)).map(WrapMap(_))
seq3: Seq[WrapMap[Int,Int]] = List(WrapMap(Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)), WrapMap(Map(5 -> 6)), WrapMap(Map(8 -> 9)))

scala> val ds = seq3.toDS()
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[WrapMap[Int,Int]] = [m: map<int,int>]

scala> ds.collect().foreach(println)
WrapMap(Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4))
WrapMap(Map(5 -> 6))
WrapMap(Map(8 -> 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zipWithIndex` and then take you `Map` post `Dataset` creation.

```
val fd: Dataset[Map[Int, Int]] =
    Seq(Map(1->2, 3->4), Map(5->6), Map(8->9)).zipWithIndex.toDS().map(_._1)
```